# Brewing cheap beer for use in garden not drinking?

Tags: beer, recipe

does anyone have any recipes that produces beer really cheaply. I have several slug traps in my garden to get rid of slugs/snails and I currently buy cheap beer from the shop, but it's a pain having to get 4 packs every week, it would be easier if i could just have a large container which I can fill my Slug Traps up from.

I'm looking for something that would cost £1.30 per Litre or less to produce and it doesn't have to taste nice or even be safe as it will be Not for Human Consumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly attracts slugs to beer. I would try to find out what specifically that is and replicate that as it might be cheaper.

However, in general it would be quite hard for you to brew beer cheaper than than the cheapest beer you can buy. Rather, doing so would probably require you to have some equipment, buying which would negate any cost saving. If you value your time at any cost, I don't think you would ever come out ahead.

But, you could mill a pound of barley, soak it a few liters of water at 150F for 20 minutes, drop in 5 grams of hops, pull the grain and boil the wort for half an hour, cool it and pitch some cheap bakers yeast and make something akin to beer after a few days.

That said- I have no idea what the cost of ingredients are for you, and in any case I really doubt you can make beer much cheaper than buying really cheap beer. However this I'm familiar with costs in the US, so I can't be 100% positive.

Comment: I believe it’s the yeast that attracts them, then the liquid and alcohol that kills them

Comment: Well, you can make a cheap low alcohol solution very simply by mixing a few cups of sugar into a few liters of water, add some champagne yeast and let it ferment for a few days. This would sort of be the brewing equivalent of putting a shot of vodka in a pint of water which once again would probably be easier. Again, I have no idea if this would indeed attract slugs.